# Get grammar scopes / tokens in vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Having defined TextMate grammar for text highlighting of a new language in Visual Studio Code, I'm now writing a DefinitionProvider. Is it possible to access the grammar tokens of the document in my extension code?

The signature of the extension method in a DefinitionProvider is:

```
provideDefinition(
    document: vscode.TextDocument,
    position: vscode.Position,
    token: vscode.CancellationToken,
  )
```

And I can't find a way to get any tokens from the document instance...

Any help is highly appreciated =)

EDIT:
Let me rephrase that: Is it possible to use the already defined TextMate grammar to navigate the code in the extension code? I would like to not write a parser on my own...

Comment: After some more digging it looks like I have to write a language server =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a service that does this now! Using my library:

```js
import TextmateLanguageService from 'vscode-textmate-languageservice';

export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const selector: vscode.DocumentSelector = 'custom';
    const textmateService = new TextmateLanguageService('custom', context);
    const textmateTokenService = await textmateService.initTokenService();
    const textDocument = vscode.window.activeTextEditor!.document;
    const tokens = textmateTokenService.fetch(textDocument);
};
```

https://github.com/vsce-toolroom/vscode-textmate-languageservice#tokenization

Comment: Thank you, but I moved away from this =D Marked it as solution anyway to give you credit for the effort. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.

Issue: [#580 Can I get scope / scopeRange at a position?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/580)